# Most efficient way to do Javascript sub-string manipulation based the following rules

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js, format

Given a String (LaTeX code) that looks like so:

ex. 1)

```
"A certain radioactive material decays exponentially.  The percent, `$P$`, of the material left after `$t$` years is given by `$P(t) = 100(1.2)^{-t}$`.\n\n**a)** Determine the half-life of the substance.\n\n**b)** How fast is the substance decaying at the point where the half-life is reached?"
```

ex. 2)

```
"Determine the equation of the tangent to `$y = 10^x$` at `$(1, 10)$`."
```

I need to format them so that I remove all the backtick (`) and the dollar signs ($). Everything between the backtick and dollar signs are LaTeX syntax (math equations). Everything else is text to go along with the math equation. I need to encapsulate the text portion with `\text{...}` as well.

So the examples should end up like so:

1)

```
"\text{A certain radioactive material decays exponentially.  The percent, }P, \text{of the material left after } t \text{years is given by } P(t) = 100(1.2)^{-t}\text{.**a)** Determine the half-life of the substance.**b)** How fast is the substance decaying at the point where the half-life is reached?}"
```

2. 

```
\text{Differentiate each of the following functions: } y= 3.1^x + x^3
```

How should I approach this to be efficient as possible? I am doing this in a Vue.JS project if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know LaTex, but this seems to meet your needs, minus a few (I think) typos in your originals:

```
var translated =
  "\\text{" + 
  original.replace(/`\$/g, "}")
          .replace(/\$`/g, " \\text{") +
  "}";
```

So that's *a* solution but I have no idea if it's *the* fastest (likely not). If you really want the fastest possible way to do this in a modern browser, I would look into Web Assembly.